# Where is this animation delay coming from in my AngularJS animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I'm using `ngShow` with a toggle to show and hide certain fields. I have it working mostly correctly, but there is a 1 second delay before it animates towards its final state.

I have my css `transition` property set to `all 1s`, so I'm wondering if it's animating to a class or style before it start's heading towards its final state.

I created a JS Bin that shows the problem:

http://jsbin.com/IQUDEdI/4/edit

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

Here's the **working** jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/IQUDEdI/8/edit

Here's the **broken** jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/IQUDEdI/4/edit

I found the solution here: http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/

The issue was the ordering and naming of the CSS. Namely, where my `transition` properties were going. I wish the documentation was more clear on this. Anyway, I'm leaving this here for posterity.